# Using "at the present" or "nowadays" at the end of the sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I want to write a sentence using "at the present" or "nowadays" at the end of my sentece but I don't know if it is totally correct.

Example:

> A Programmable Logic Control (PLC) is a device commonly used and implemented by companies at the present.

or

> A Programmable Logic Control (PLC) is a device commonly used and implemented by companies nowadays.

Are they both correct? 
Do I have to write a comma after companies?

Comment: With the first one, you do not need the definite article. The idiom is *...at present*. Otherwise they are both fine. Incidentally by *PLC* do you mean *Public Limited Company*? If so I would suggest the sentences need to be worded slightly differently.

Comment: ***Nowadays*** is a [declining usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nowadays&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnowadays%3B%2Cc0). Not exactly "quaint" yet for most native speakers - but headed in that direction, I think. Your *at the present* is non-idiomatic - normally it's just *at present* (a "noun" usage with no article). Alternatively, go for the "adjectival" form - for example,  *at **the** present **time***.

Comment: @WS2 no, with PLC I mean Programmable Logical Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of the word *nowadays* suggests a change from how things were or were done in the past.  Use of *at the present* means now, and yet does not necessarily indicate permanence.

Both would be correct usage, but correct choice would depend on the writer's intent.  As to use of a comma, it would not be correct in the case presented.